Spring Boot - Spring KafkaAdmin cannot set operation-timeout to check connectivity
Spring versions:

spring-kafka: 3.1.3
spring-boot: 3.2.2

I need to expose a healthcheck endpoint to check that a microservice which publishes to kafka is a) Up and running and b) able to connect to kafka
I am using Spring Kafka auto-configuration and creating a KafkaAdmin instance to check connectivity
in my configuration I do set spring.kafka.admin.operation-timeout=1 however this appears not to be set when I debug the code.  Therefore I came up with the following method to check connectivity:
 public boolean checkConnectivity() {
        boolean success = true;
        try {
            admin.setOperationTimeout(2);
            admin.describeTopics(this.outboundTopic).forEach((x,y) -> {
                logger.debug(String.format("Succesfully fetched TopicDescription for topic", this.outboundTopic));
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Kafka connectivity check failed", e );
            success = false;
        }

        return success;
    }

Horrible I know but admin.clusterId() returns null as I cant get the spring.kafka.template.observation-enabled=true to work - that is another question I guess!
Even though hard coding the operation timeout has no effect.
Did try to pass Kafka properties, but didnt really help:
spring.kafka.admin.properties[socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms]=1000
spring.kafka.admin.properties[socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms]=1000
spring.kafka.admin.properties[retries]=1

Seems to go through 3 rounds of 30 retries before failing with a Failed to obtain topic descriptions exception!
Ultimately the healthcheck works - but takes about a minute to fail - wondering if there is a way to speed up!
Wondering if  I am missing a trick here - ideally would be able to quickly test connectivity as part of a health check to identify any Kafka connectivity issues?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have created by own AdminClient bean using the spring boot auto config properties I use for spring auto config and the following works well admin.describeCluster().clusterId().get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); when wrapped in a try..catch block
